# Windows memory logged on vs logged off

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

Let's say I power on my fresh installed Windows 7 x64 machine. After Windows boots up, there are a bunch of services being started in the background that start allocating memory.

Then I enter my user/pass and Windows logs me in.
Let's supose I don't do anythig else (I don't explicitely start any application) and I don't have any other app installed by me. So it's fresh install of my machine.

My question is: how much memory is needed for all the UI & other stuff?
Is it a good indicator to look into task manager and check all the processes started under my user name and sum up all the memory consumed by those processes to get the total amount of memory I am consuming just to stay logged on? Basically this is my question: how much memory is needed just to stay logged on?

Now, if log off would all the memory be released back to the system so that the background services can benefit of?

Also, I assume that there might be a different discussion for each Windows flavors (?)

Comment: Your procedure to look at task manager and to sum up the memory used by applications that you own looks good to me. As I only have a Win7 with a lot of stuff installed at hand, you'll have to check the memory needed yourself :-).

Comment: @WernerHenze, thank you, but no other system processes need to be fired once I log in? should be negligible?

Comment: Good point. There could be system services configured to run manually and a program in your autostart folder might start the service but not stop it when terminating, so the service keeps running even after logoff. But I would not care about that. If you want to know the memory difference exactly, you can start performance monitor on a second computer and connect to your computer. Or you can write a service yourself which dumps the memory usage over time to a file.

Answer (score 0):

First off I will say that generally speaking, from experience, 2 GB is the minimum usable for Win 7.  4 GB if you use it with any regularity.  (MS states that 1 GB is the minimum but good luck with that.)  64 bit installs will require more memory.

Any processes that are started under your account will be terminated once you log out.  I would think that the memory management algorithm will more than likely be the same for all Win 7 variants as this is a core function of the OS, but would almost certainly be different in XP vs Vista vs Win 7 (though the latter two are more closely related than to XP).

What I can tell you is hardware availability has somewhat influenced memory management.  RAM is super cheap nowawdays, and OS programmers have realized that 'free' memory can be put to better use as a super fast cache.  Basically the OS will remember/learn your most used apps and data and cache that in RAM.  I'm sure there is much, much more to it but I'm not an expert on OS design, perhaps someone else can chime in.

Also it's impossible to predict an exact amount of memory usage, there are far too many variables involved (see above), but the easiest way to check your particular instance would be to use Resource Monitor